# Jasonette - .replace.string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, jasonette

I am trying to replace part of a url address when a link is clicked.

If the url is mysite.com/photos/ i would like to replace mysite.net with another url say yorsite.net/photos/.

If someone could please let me know how to go about this.

What i have tried so far

```js
{{#if /\\/(mysite.net)$/.test.($jason.url.replace('mysite.net/',
'yoursite.net')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
{
    "{{#elseif $jason.url.indexOf('mysite.net') !== -1  }}": {
        "type": "$href",
        "options": {
            "url": "{{$jason.url.replace(mysite.net/, 'yoursite.net')}}",
            "view": "web"
        }
    }
}
```